# How do you restart a mod-mono asp.net application from command line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, mod-mono

I have an asp.net MVC web app running on mod-mono under Apache2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I want to drop a new assembly into my app, without having to restart Apache as a whole.

I see from [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Control_panel) that you can install the mono control panel and restart applications there. That's fine, but I don't really want that enabled on a production system.

Is there a way to do it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you disabled file change notifications a simple "touch web.config" (make sure to use the actual casing of your file) should do it.

Otherwise a more hardcore approach would be to kill the mod-mono processes (they'll be restarted automatically).